# phpdocumentor v2 --template cli option invalid

Tags: php, phpdoc

From the docs when I run the following command

```
phpdoc -d ../../src/ -t /tmp/domain-model-docs --template="responsive-twig"
```

I get this error

```
ERROR: Unknown command-line option "--template=responsive-twig" encountered, use phpdoc -h for help

ERROR: Unknown command-line option "--template=responsive-twig" encountered, use phpdoc -h for help
```

The docs state

```
$ phpdoc -d "./src" -t "./docs/api" --template="clean"
```

However, in the help that option does not exist (phpdoc -h).

Has it been renamed?

Comment: This error looks like phpDocumentor 1.x, and that argument is only in 2.x. Info on 1.x is at http://manual.phpdoc.org/, whereas info on 2.x is at http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/running-phpdocumentor.html.

Answer (score 0):

After more work & investigation, I got the following error...

```
vagrant@packer-ubuntu-13:/var/www/opg-core-back-end$ vendor/bin/phpdoc.php
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Monolog\ErrorHandler' not found in /var/www/opg-core-back-end/vendor/phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor/src/phpDocumentor/Application.php on line 131
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/opg-core-back-end/vendor/phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor/bin/phpdoc.php:0
PHP   2. phpDocumentor\Application->__construct() /var/www/opg-core-back-end/vendor/phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor/bin/phpdoc.php:26
PHP   3. phpDocumentor\Application->addLogging() /var/www/opg-core-back-end/vendor/phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor/src/phpDocumentor/Application.php:57
```

Then I found out that monolog was an older version due to the ElasticSearch client after specifying phpdocumentor to use v2.3 rather than v2.* in composer & got this error...

```
our requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for elasticsearch/elasticsearch 0.4.0 -> satisfiable by elasticsearch/elasticsearch[v0.4.0].
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.3.0 requires monolog/monolog ~1.6 -> satisfiable by monolog/monolog[1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.8.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: monolog/monolog[1.6.0, 1.5.0].
    - Can only install one of: monolog/monolog[1.7.0, 1.5.0].
    - Can only install one of: monolog/monolog[1.8.0, 1.5.0].
    - Can only install one of: monolog/monolog[1.8.x-dev, 1.5.0].
    - elasticsearch/elasticsearch v0.4.0 requires monolog/monolog 1.5.0 -> satisfiable by monolog/monolog[1.5.0].
    - Installation request for phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor 2.3 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor[v2.3.0].
```

To generate the class diagram, I temporary removed ElasticSearch dependency from composer. Not a long term solution, but allowed me to get the domain model diagram.